# Why I can`t find Class "OpenAI\API\Request"?

Tags: php, openai-api

I use openai/client-php.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use OpenAI\Client;
use OpenAI\API\Request;

$yourApiKey = 'sk-fEpZ.......';
$client = new Client(new Request($yourApiKey));

function generateText($client, $model, $prompt, $length, $temperature = 0.5) {
    $response = $client->completions()->create(
        $model,
        [
            'prompt' => $prompt,
            'max_tokens' => $length,
            'temperature' => $temperature,
        ]
    );
    return $response['choices'][0]['text'];
}


$models = [
    'en' => 'text-davinci-002',
    'zh' => 'text-davinci-002',
    'de' => 'text-davinci-002',
    'fr' => 'text-davinci-002'
];

$languages = [
    'en' => 'English',
    'zh' => 'Chinese',
    'de' => 'German',
    'fr' => 'French'
];

$prompt = 'Why the sky is blue?:';

foreach ($models as $lang => $model) {
    $generatedText = generateText($client, $model, $prompt, 200);
    $generatedTitle = substr($generatedText, 0, 80);
    echo " {$languages[$lang]} Language:\n";
    echo "Title: $generatedTitle\n";
    echo "Text: $generatedText\n\n";
}
```

I have error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "OpenAI\API\Request" not found in
> D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\openai\test.php:9 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\openai\test.php on
> line 9

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any class called `API/Request` in the library source code. It should be,

```php
use OpenAI\Client;

$yourApiKey = 'sk-fEpZ.......';
$client = new Client($yourApiKey);
```

**OR**

```
$yourApiKey = 'sk-fEpZ.......';
$client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

Comment: I have already tried these options. I'm going in circles. When you start doing more complex functions, errors start coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation: https://github.com/openai-php/client
Client is created in other way:

```
$yourApiKey = getenv('YOUR_API_KEY');
$client = OpenAI::client($yourApiKey);
```

Comment: I have error/ Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: OpenAI\Resources\Completions::create(): Argument #1 ($parameters) must be of type array, string given, called in D:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\openai\test.php on line 17